# Differential Equation for improper integrals

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform

How do I use the definiton of the improper integral to find the Laplace transform $F(s)$ for the function $f(t)=e^{(t-1)^2}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and have tried anything. It really helps to share those thoughts. Regards

Answer (score 1):

This Laplace transform does not exist.  Why?

From Boyce and DiPrima's Elementary Differential Equations:

> **Theorem 6.1.2:**
>   Suppose that:
>
> 1. $f$ is piecewise continuous on the interval $0\le t\le A$ for any positive $A$
> 2. $|f(t)| \le Ke^{at}$ when $t\ge M$.  In this inequality, $K$, $a$, and $M$ are real constants, $K$, $M$ necessarily positive.
>
> Then the Laplace Transform $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = F(s)$, defined by Eq. $(4)$, exists for $s \gt a$.

The problem we have is that $f(t) = e^{(t-1)^2}$ is not of exponential order--the $a$ and $K$ values above don't exist for this function.

Comment: But this wouldn't turn into an integral and then I go from there?

Comment: @user75629 Yeah, but note that it's an improper integral.  The integral ends up diverging.

Comment: So it would diverge to infinity, right?

Comment: @user75629 It looks as if it should go to $+\infty$. I didn't compute the integral by hand (CAS for the win!), so I don't know for sure, but I don't see how it could possibly go negative.

Answer (score 0):

Well the formal definition of the Laplace transform is:

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{f(t)\right\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$$

Here, your function is $f(t)=e^{(t-1)^2}$ so your Laplace transform is:

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}e^{(t-1)^2}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{(t-1)^2-st}dt$$

Work this one out and you'll find what you want

**Edit:** As @anorton noted, this integral is divergent. Indeed, if you expand the exponent you get:

$$(t-1)^2-st=t^2-(s+2)t+1=\left(t-\frac{s+2}{2}\right)^2+\left(1-\left(\frac{s+2}{2}\right)^2\right)$$

so your integral becomes:

$$\large F(s)=e^{1-\left(\tfrac{s+2}{2}\right)^2}\int_0^\infty e^{\left(t-\tfrac{s+2}{2}\right)^2}dt$$

Now a variable change gives you:

$$\large F(s)=e^{1-\left(\tfrac{s+2}{2}\right)^2}\int_{-\tfrac{s+2}{2}}^\infty e^{x^2}dx$$

Which diverges.

**Note:**

Your function can be written as:

$$f(t)=e\cdot e^{-2t}\cdot e^{t^2}$$

$e$ is a constant so from the linearity of the Laplace transform, you have:

$$F(s)=\mathcal{L}\left\{f(t)\right\}=e\cdot\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{-2t}\cdot e^{t^2}\right\}$$

Now, you have another property that states that: If $G(s)$ is the Laplace transform of a function $g(t)$, then the Laplace transform of $e^{\lambda t}g(t)$ is $G(s-\lambda)$.

Here $g(t)=e^{t^2}$ and $\lambda=-2$ so you have:

$$F(s)=e\cdot G(s+2)$$

Where $G(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $e^{t^2}$. But $e^{t^2}$ doesn't have a Laplace transform, so neither does $f(t)$

Are you sure your function has to have a Laplace transform ? In which case maybe there's a mistake in it. Like for example $f(t)=\left(e^{(t-1)}\right)^2$ instead of $f(t)=e^{(t-1)^2}$

Comment: That's where I got and I am not quite sure how to integrate this. I also expanded the (t-1)^2 -st

Comment: The integral diverges. (per [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20exp%28%28t-1%29^2%20-st%29%20dt%20from%200%20to%20infinity&t=ff3tb01), at least.)

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't really look at it carefully, but yes, with some factoring and variable change, you end up with a divergent integral: $\displaystyle\int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{x^2}dx$

Comment: Yes I am sure it's e^(t-1)^2. Maybe it's a problem trying to through me off?

Comment: Ok, well then yeah the answer's just to say that since the improper integral used to compute $F(s)$ diverges, $f(t)$ doesn't have a Laplace transform.